# Webpack error loading CSS Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, reactjs, webpack

I have an AngularJS (I know, very old!) application. In this app, I'm trying to include a React component, with the help of react2angular. The intention is to migrate the existing AngularJS code to React.

Anyway, I'm using `Webpack`, and as instructed, have defined the CSS loaders in the `webpack.config.js` as follows

```
module: {
  ...
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
  }
}
```

And in my React component JS, I have the following imports:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Spinner from 'react-bootstrap/Spinner';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

However, on running the app, I see the following:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.loader (/....../node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:84:33)
@ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 2:26-86
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Despite my extensive Googling, I haven't managed to resolve this, and had to give up the approach, in favour of using a conventional `<link>` to the CSS file in the index.html

Comment: hello - did you save this at all? Had the same issue for a day now :-/